# How to choose design\platform for a product?

Tags: architecture, product

I have an idea for a product, to be used by am individual.I would like to have a web application with offline mode capability.But,I  also want the application to be available on mobiles.How can I achieve offline capability which works both on the desktop n mobile.
thanks

Comment: In the next years there will be no more diference on desktop or mobile platforms. Any mobile will be (or today is) as powerfull as a today desktop. 
In the next years working offline will have no sense anymore. Even today what can you really do offline and how long can you wait to get online again before all you have done in offline is obsolete ? 
I'm really interested what's your product doing offline.

Comment: information related to family.I thought privacy could be an issue

Comment: In the countries with emerging economy, internet connectivity is still an issue. If you go to country side, there is no connectivity. That said, it is always a good option to have offline access to your online data.

Answer (score 0):

Do an assessment of your options from the platform level first.

Maturity of web frameworks and mobile functionality will be key, but some of the other things you should consider are:

- Development costs (open source or licenced)
- Development ease
- Fit within a technology stack (SQL / Win / .Net / Asp.net vs. Oracle / Solaris / Tomcat / Java EE vs. LAMP etc.)
- Availability of skill sets for development and support

Your options are for web / disconnected / desktop / mobile could fit in any of the platforms above, plus some others.

Choose carefully, and Good luck!

Comment: I agree with Kaiser, you could add Community to the considerations. If a stack or technology has a large community it will mean more resources (tutorials, articles, forums) in general.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your application is for personal use. And since you are on SO, I can assume that you are a developer yourself. If this is the case, you have to answer following questions:

1. Which language/platform you are
   comfortable with?
2. What are the free tools available?
3. Does the platform support RAD (Rapid
   Application Development)?
4. Can you use any free database or you
   have to invest in the DB?
5. Where you are going to host your
   application? What platforms are
   supported by the hosting service
   provider?

For design, pl post some of the high level requirements/functionality of the application so that people can suggest something on that.